# MalformedJsonException error

Tags: android, json, gradle, jsonreader

It happened when I restarted my computer.
I turn on android studio, but I can't start the emulator.

[image]

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
```

Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 1m 32s
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: looks like your json data is wrong. could you put in the question?

Comment: We can help you better if you include a sample of the JSON source, the code you are using to parse that source and indicate the line in the code where the error is throw.